# Nothing executes after forEach loop in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, functional-programming

My redux code looks like following

```
const getCategories =  (res) => (dispatch,getState) => {
  let categories = []
  const result = res.results
  console.log("here")
  result.forEach((rawMaterial,index)=>{
     if(!_.includes(categories,rawMaterial.category[0].name)){

       categories.push(rawMaterial.category[0].name)
       dispatch({type:UPDATE_CATEGORIES,categories})
     }
  });
  console.log("here2")
}
```

Basically it is a function which pushes data into categories array from input parameter "res". What my problem is, "getCategories" function does not executes anything after forEach loop. 
The below piece of chunk does not get executed in the above code.

```
console.log("here2")
```

Function executes nothing after forEach loop.

Full code

```
export const getRawMaterials = (params = {}) => (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  { fetch }
) => {

  dispatch({ type: GET_RAW_MATERIALS_REQUEST, params });
  const { token } = dispatch(getToken());
  const { search, ordering } = getState().rawMaterials;
  return fetch(
    `/pands/raw-materials/?${qs.stringify({
      search,
      ordering
    })}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      token,
      success: res => {
        const rawMaterials = res.results
        dispatch({ type: GET_RAW_MATERIALS_SUCCESS, res });

        const categories = getCategories(rawMaterials);

        dispatch({type:UPDATE_CATEGORIES,categories})
      },
      failure: err => dispatch({ type: GET_RAW_MATERIALS_FAILURE })
    }
  );
};

//doubt here, function get return after forEach
const getCategories = (res) => {
  let categories = []
  const result = res;
  return result.map(rawMaterial => {
    if(_.includes(categories,rawMaterial.category[0].name)) return null;
    return rawMaterial.category[0].name;
    }
  )
}
```

My code is not working from the following line:

```
const categories = getCategories(rawMaterials);
```

Neither it is giving an error. I think problem is with response coming from backend.

"res" is coming from backend. my data is in "res.results". When I type check "res.results" , it shows object but when I print it, it shows array of objects.

Comment: Is this some simple contrived example, or actual code in you app? My gut instinct is that your functional parameters are reversed, but I think more context it necessary. Can you provide a running codesandbox that repros this issue?

Comment: Apart from your question, this actions looks like it would be better to process the entire array before dispatching anything. Why dispatch a bunch of "UPDATE_CATEGORIES" actions very fast? This will hit every reducer and mapStateToProps function in your app for every single one of the actions, which you probably don't want. The user isn't fast enough to react to such quick updates or even notice what's happening.

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited and added full code. My app is very big so we would not be able to put it on codesandbox

Comment: FYI, you only need to create a sandbox that repros your issue, not the full app code. Sometimes you'll find the error when you break it down to a simpler case. Why is the `getCategories` function snippet you say has an issue different from the `getCategories` function from your full code? It has a completely different signature and returns a mapped result array. Please share your response shape, i.e. what is the actual object shape of `res`?

Comment: @DrewReese I solved the issue, actually the response that I was getting from the backend had the flaw. One entry was not providing category , that's why entire code got hung up